# Getting the "name" of XML elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML that looks something like this:

```
<signals>
  <signal name="N$41">
  </signal>
  <signal name="S$80">
  </signal>
</signals>
```

I am wondering how and if it is possible to get the name, i.e. "N$41" from each signal?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. But what have you tried?

Comment: the term is "attribute value"

Comment: So what have you tried and how vast is your understanding of xml, are you familiar with XDocument?

Comment: `/signals/signal/@name` in XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `XDocument`

```
var result = XDocument.Load(filename).Descendants("signal");

foreach (var p in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Attribute("name"));
}
```